# Characterization of $L_{\mathrm{loc} }^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ functions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, lp-spaces

I would like to know if, when it comes to checking if $f\in L_{\mathrm{loc}}^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$, instead of checking if $f\in L^p(K)$ for every open $K\subset\subset \mathbb{R}^n$, if it suffices to check that $f\in L^p(K)$ for some class of $K\subset\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ that is *nice* (i.e., something like $\partial K$ of class $C^1$, etc.). That is, I want to know if there exist *nice sets* $K\subset\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ such that if $f\in L^p(K)$ for all such $K$, then $f\in L_{\mathrm{loc}}^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

Comment: You could consider $K$s to be balls.

Comment: Of course, because $f\in L^p(K)$ (i.e. $\int_K |f(x)|^pdx <\infty$) implies $f\in L^p(M)$ for all (measurable) $M\subseteq K$.

Comment: @Jochen Thanks! And I suppose the same thing applies to $f\in W^{1,p}_{loc}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ (i.e. we can check it only for balls).